# Eclipse RCP View with form does not refresh

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm learning how to create an Eclipse RCP application with forms, and I'm building a simple prototype of what I need to do so.  I'm using 64 bit Eclipse 3.7 and Java 1.7 on a Windows x64 platform.

What I'm trying to do is fairly standard:  A view on the left of the app contains a tree (`ViewTree`), and a view on the right (`ViewDetail`) uses eclipse forms to present the detailed information regarding the tree selection.  I set `ViewTree` to be a selection provider, and `ViewDetail` is set to listen to `ViewTree`.  I want `ViewDetail` to refresh itself with every new tree selection.

Here is the relevant code for `ViewTree`:

```
public class ViewTree extends ViewPart
{
    private TreeViewer treeViewer;

    public ViewTree() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);
        treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new TreeObjLabelProvider());
        treeViewer.setContentProvider(new TreeObjContentProvider());
    }
```

Here is the relevant code for `ViewDetail`:

```
public class ViewDetail extends ViewPart implements ISelectionListener 
{
    private FormToolkit toolkit;
    private ScrolledForm form;
    private Composite compParent;

    public ViewDetail() {}

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
        form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
        compParent = parent;
        // register as a selection listener with the workbench
        getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(ViewTree.ID, (ISelectionListener) this);
    }
```

Because I want the form in `ViewDetail` to erase itself and redraw with the new information for every new selection, in the `selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection)` function of ViewDetail, I call
`form.dispose();`
to erase it and then recreate the form using:
`form = toolkit.createScrolledForm(compParent);`
I then determine what type of object has been selected and build the form accordingly.

The problem is that once I select an object in the tree, my form is disposed of and the `ViewDetail` goes blank.  Nothing will show up in the view until the window is resized.  Once the form has been built, I attempt to refresh it by calling:
`form.getBody().layout();`
but this does not seem to help.  Any ideas as to what to try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the form to redraw without resizing by calling:

```
compParent.layout();
```

So I was on the right track with the layout command, I just needed to call it on the top level - the parent Composite, instead of the form, which is a child of the parent Composite.  Thanks @GGeorge for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do `form.layout(true)` directly.

OR

You can even try `form.reflow()`.

**Edit:**

[Further reading on the topic, here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecgui1/). Read the "Listening for events" section.

Comment: I tried these suggestions but neither of them work.  The link you shared is interesting but I think my issue lies in how I'm using Eclipse Forms, and the article does not mention them.  The selection and listening part of my code works fine - the problem I'm having is that the detail view is not being drawn on a selection.  Only when the window is resized does the form get shown.

Comment: When the window is resized, a reflow is triggered on the form. That's why my first response was to do a reflow... Have you seen this  http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_examples/ ? I recon these examples are very similar to yours.

Comment: I have seen that link you mention before - it has some excellent examples that are very similar to what I'm doing, but unfortunately the examples don't seem to work in Eclipse 3.7 (or newer) and none of the examples I see use Eclipse Forms.  I'm beginning to think there isn't that much information about Eclipse Forms out there because they don't work very well...